# A better algorithm to get the non-highlighted text from a semi-highlighted text

Tags: java, string, algorithm

**The context**:

I have a text document that has some sentences in it highlighted. To locate the highlighted parts, I have a list that contains the start and stop positions of the highlighted parts. To get the highlighted parts, one can easily use Java's `string.substring(start, stop)` method. However, getting the non-highlighted parts is pretty tricky.

**The problem:**

My ultimate goal is to tokenize the text in the document and then assign a label for each token as either highlighted or not. Thus, what I ultimately need is to have two lists: 1- one list that contains the highlighted text chunks, 2- another list that contains the non-highlighted text chunks. Then, I would simply tokenize each chunk separately in each list.

The problem I'm facing is finding a clean algorithm to extract the non-highlighted text chunks. As I said, getting the highlighted chunks is easy because you already have their start and end positions and you can use Java's `string.substring(start, stop)` method.

For example:

```
This is a simple text, **this part is highlighted**, this part is not but **this is also highlighted,** but this one is also not.
```

The non-highlighted text chunks list should thus contain:

1 - `This is a simple text,`

2- `, this part is not but`

3-  `but this one is also not.`

**My approach:**

The way I'm solving this problem is by adding the start and end positions of the highlighted parts into a hash table, where the start positions are keys and the values are the end positions. Then I start reading the text document character-by-character and check if the current character's position is a key in the hash table, if so I consider all already-read characters as a non-highlighted text chunk and add it to the non-highlighted text chunks list.

However, I find my approach kinda ugly and I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. I'm not good in String algorithms, and thought that there might be better approaches for this.

**So my question**: is there a better way to find the non-highlighted text chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your highlight locations in a list and sort them by start position. For each highlight in the list except the last, there is a non-highlighted area that starts on the end position of that highlight and ends on the start position of the subsequent highlight. Also, unless the first start position is 0, there is a non-highlighted area from 0 to the first start, and similarly for the last highlight.

(This assumes that there are no overlapping highlights - if there are, you first need go through the list and merge overlapping highlights. You can detect an overlap by checking if the end of one highlight is after the start of the subsequent highlight.)

Comment: After reading your approach I kinda found myself too stupid :(

Comment: Surely, I myself have _never_ stared the obvious in the face and missed it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is pop a pair of start and end positions of the highlighted text such that start is the smallest. Then I would construct a new pair that would represent start and end positions of unhighlighted text up to that point. So:

1. As this is the first iteration, first = 0 //first represents start position of unhighlighted text
2. Pop pair (min_start, min_end) from highlighted map
3. Construct pair (first, min_start - 1) and add to unhighlighted map
4. first = min_end //Or min_end + 1 if it's a closed interval
5. Loop steps 2-4 until highlighted map is empty
6. Add final pair (first, end_of_document) to the list